# Sqlite error: Could not reset the virtual machine

Tags: c++, sqlite, csv

I am trying to read from a csv file and add each row to a database in c++. The csv file is in the form `id,firstname,surname,job` my code is:

```
while (file.good())
        {
          getline (file, id, ',');
          getline (file, firstname, ',');
          getline (file, surname, ',');
          getline (file, job, ' ');

          cur->set_sql( "INSERT INTO staff VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);" );
          cur->prepare();

          cur->bind(1, id);
          cur->bind(2, firstname);
          cur->bind(3, surname);
          cur->bind(4, job);
          cur->step();

          cur->reset();
        }
```

but when I run the code it returns the error `Sqlite error: Could not reset the virtual machine.` I do not understand what this means or how to solve it. I searched the error on google but I can't find anything about it

Comment: Have you looked at the return code of step?

Comment: @UKMonkey it returns 0

Comment: Call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to get the actual error message.

Comment: @CL. It returns `1` which means `sqlite_error`

Comment: `sqlite3_errmsg()` does not return a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve this error. I realised I was programming on a virtual machine and all I needed to do was restart it. There was nothing wrong with my code!

Answer (score 0):

Error comes from `libsqlite.hpp` (check search on github.com)

```
void reset(){
        int rc = sqlite3_reset(this->_s);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            exception e("Could not reset the virtual machine.");
            throw e;
        }
        this->_valid = true;
        this->_has_row = false;
        this->_prepared = false;
}
```

I haven't digg into this but it looks like sqilte query contain error or can't run.